# CHtml submit button is not working when 'enter' key press in Yii

Tags: yii

In my Yii web application, CHtml submit button is not working when 'enter' key press in Login form. My login form is,

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
<h3 class="form-title">Login to your account</h3>
<div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
<button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
<span> Enter any username and password. </span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Username</label>
<div class="input-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'username', array("class" => "form-control placeholder-no-fix", 'placeholder' => "Username")) ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
<div class="input-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($model, 'password', array("class" => "form-control placeholder-no-fix", 'placeholder' => "Password")) ?>
</div>
</div><br>
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton(UserModule::t("Login "), array('class' => 'btn green pull-right')); ?>
</div>
<div class="text-danger"><?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model); ?></div>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?><br><br><br>
<?php
$form = new CForm(array(
'elements' => array(
    'username' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'maxlength' => 32,
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'maxlength' => 32,
    ),
    'rememberMe' => array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
    )
),
'buttons' => array(
    'login' => array(
        'type' => 'submit',
        'label' => 'Login',
    ),
),
    ), $model);
?>
```

In this login form using chtml submit button. I want to submit this login form by press enter key.
How to resolve this problem.
Please help me.

Comment: UserModule::t("Login ") ,here for what purpose you used usermodule::t?

Comment: Actually UserModule::t("Login ")  for just label only.

Comment: Just use a onclick event in the submit button for redirection.

Comment: How to give onclick event in CHtml::submitButton

Comment: Do you have event listeners with Javascript on your custom 'form-control' and/or 'placeholder-no-fix' html classes? Probably you are filtering ENTER keypress with Javascript over these fields or over all your forms

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to use onclick:

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitbutton(UserModule::t("Login "), array('class ' => 'btn green pull-right', 'onclick' => ' '));?>
```

Comment: I am updating my question with total code. In that code using Usermodule for validation and labels.